# Error al ejecutar sdk de facebook

Tags: facebook

Buen dia amigos.
Soy muy nuevo en esto de la configuracion de las api de facebook.
Desde mi web quiero logearme a mi aplicativo de fcebook y me sale lo que muestro en las imagenes.
[image: Captura de pantalla]

Como puedo solucionar este error, estoy buscando en San Google y no encuentro ninguna respuesta a ello.
Les agradezco infinitamente.

Comment: Agreaga algo de codigo para poder ver tu conexion y si configuraste bien tus **"keys"**

Comment: Gracias @Shassain, ya logre accede; solo falto configurar el oAuth.